# How to Remove Indicator under Horizontal Scroll Menu

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontalscrollview

I created horizontal scroll menu as shown in w3schools how to guide, 
but my problem is, 
it shows a line/indicator while scrolling, 
i want to Remove that line.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp

How can i remove that Line/Indicator?

Comment: can you explain what line? do you mean to scroll bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Do you mean horizontal scrollbar on scrolling.?

Comment: @rash.tay thanks, that's exactly what i need, that's worked.